# Adding JCombobox in Jtable and Getting that Row and Column in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have One Jtable in which i have added JComobox like this.

```
TableColumn sportColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
        comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
        comboBox.addItem("Chasing toddlers");
        comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
        comboBox.addItem("Teaching high school");
        comboBox.addItem("None");
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

and i have added one mouse event of jtable like this.

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            int row = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
            int col = jTable1.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());

            System.out.println("Row" + row + "Column" + col);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and i am getting proper out put of row and column.[image]

but when i click on the cell where i added Jcombobox that time its not giving out put of that row and column. still i have called clickevent of table in combobox click event but its giving all time row 0 and even column 0 here screen shot.

[image]

so how do i solved it so i can have that row and column?

Comment: So you why are you trying to get the column/row info for?

Comment: @MadProgrammer M trying to get that column/row but i am getting that where i have not added combobox. but when i cliced combobox its not giving. that

Comment: The combo box will be told the cell it is editing when getTableCellEditorComponent is called. Remember, mouse clicks are contextual to the component they were raised in

Comment: @MadProgrammer M not gettin :( can u please tell me how to make it :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer can u help me for the same?

Comment: So, the problem is, when you click the column which is assigned the combo box editor, you're not getting the right row/column for the tables mouse listener?

Comment: ya that time not getting Comumn number and row number when i clicked on jcombo

Comment: Okay, is the cell in edit mode (ie is the combo box visible)?

Comment: yes when i clicked on cell then comobox is visible.

Comment: While the combo box is visible, the table can't recieve mouse events as the combo box is blocking them

Comment: @MadProgrammer So how to recover it i need that count any how.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I just need that which cell is clicked so i can have that data if user change that combobox state and i need that changed state data or index of that changed state.

Comment: You do realise that 1- You could do this just from the combo box itself and 2- Once editing stops, the selected value will be returned to the `TableModel` via the `setValueAt` method automatically...?

Comment: but how could i do it?

Comment: The question is why?  Why do you need to know that the combo box selection has changed?  What are you doing with it?  What happens if they change the selected item through the keyboard?

Comment: Well i just need that changed data because i need to send it in service @MadProgrammer bro.

Comment: Okay, so you have two choices.  Add a [`TableModelListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) to the table and monitor for changes to the table model or add a [`CellEditorListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/CellEditorListener.html) to the combo box cell editor and monitor for the `editingStopped` event.  This is probably saver, as the user may change there mind before they've completed editing the cell...

Comment: @MadProgrammer bro its kinda something confusing can u show me demo please can u do me favor :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see it, you have three basic options...

### You Could...

Attach a `CellEditorListener` to the `DefaultCellEditor` and monitor for `editingStopped` events...

```
editor.addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {
    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Editing stopped");
        TableCellEditor editor = (TableCellEditor) e.getSource();
        Object value = editor.getCellEditorValue();
        System.out.println("Selected value = " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
    }
});
```

The problem with this, is it's not possible to actually determine the cell that's been edited.  Even with a reference to the `JTable`, by the time you receive this event, the table is no longer in edit mode...So all you know is the value of the editor...

### You Could...

Attach a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`...

```
model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int type = e.getType();
        switch (type) {
            case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                if (e.getFirstRow() - e.getLastRow() == 0) {
                    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                    int row = e.getFirstRow();
                    int col = e.getColumn();
                    System.out.println("Update " + row + "x" + col + " = " + model.getValueAt(row, col));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

This will let you know when the value of a cell has changed (and a lot of other things, but this is what we're interested), what it won't tell you, is why it changed.

This approach is good, because it provides all the information you need to know in order to find the value and the cell.

### You Could...

Simply override the `TableModel`'s `setValueAt` method and provide some sort of notification of your own...

While this is kind of duplicating the functionality of the `TableModelListener` you could devise the event information so that it provides more relevant information as the `TableModelEvent` covers a lot of user cases...

**Example**

Below is an example taken [TableRenderDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableRenderDemoProject/src/components/TableRenderDemo.java) and modified to to demonstrate the first two concepts

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * TableRenderDemo is just like TableDemo, except that it explicitly initializes
 * column sizes and it uses a combo box as an editor for the Sport column.
 */
public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Set up column sizes.
        initColumnSizes(table);

        //Fiddle with the Sport column's cell editors/renderers.
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /*
     * This method picks good column sizes.
     * If all column heads are wider than the column's cells'
     * contents, then you can just use column.sizeWidthToFit().
     */
    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int type = e.getType();
                switch (type) {
                    case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                        if (e.getFirstRow() - e.getLastRow() == 0) {
                            TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                            int row = e.getFirstRow();
                            int col = e.getColumn();
                            System.out.println("Update " + row + "x" + col + " = " + model.getValueAt(row, col));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer
                        = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                            null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                            false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).
                            getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                            table, longValues[i],
                                            false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(final JTable table,
                    TableColumn sportColumn) {
        //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
        comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
        comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
        comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
        comboBox.addItem("Pool");
        comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
        TableCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
        editor.addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {

            @Override
            public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Editing stopped");
                TableCellEditor editor = (TableCellEditor) e.getSource();
                Object value = editor.getCellEditorValue();
                System.out.println("Selected value = " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
            }
        });
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(editor);

        //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer
                        = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy",
            "None of the above",
            new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yaa Perfect Example @MadProgrammer.

Comment: @Krishna Took a little effort but we dragged it kicking and screaming across the line ;)

Comment: Perfect answer.  Life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you can get values of selected rows and column.
[image]

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
      {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            try {
                int rowss = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                System.out.println("rowss" + rowss);
                printDebugData(table);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ShowEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData(JTable jTable1) throws ParseException
        {
              String selectedData = null;

            int numRows = jTable1.getRowCount();
            int numCols = jTable1.getColumnCount();
            int[] selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
            int[] selectedColumns = jTable1.getSelectedColumns();
            javax.swing.table.TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) 
                {
                    selectedData = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
                }
                System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
            }
        }
        });

  }
```

check with mouselistner with your jtbale.

**UPDATE :**
add this two line before printdebugdata() called.

```
  int rowss = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
  System.out.println("rowss" + rowss);
```

I got the row number check my output.

**OUTPUT :**

```
rowss0
Selected: Smith
rowss0
Selected: Smith
rowss1
Selected: Snowboarding
rowss1
Selected: Rowing
rowss1
Selected: Rowing
rowss1
Selected: Rowing
rowss2
Selected: Snowboarding
rowss2
Selected: Snowboarding
rowss2
Selected: Snowboarding
rowss2
Selected: Snowboarding
```

Thanks..

Comment: M trying. i will let u know.

Comment: m not getting row num and col num

Comment: sorry bro not working its not giving when i use Conbobox event

Comment: @Krishna: no use my latest update. no need to work with combobox event.

Comment: @krishna: I got output using same code. and my console is also there.. then check your side.. where is mistake?

Comment: there is prob when i clicked Jcombo try to paste that code of Jcombo how u add it.

Answer (score 0):

Well Its Little But strange for me but ya i do solved it but i dont think so that is the proper ansewer but i solved it. i called. Combo button Action Performed event and have called Mouse click of jtable in that. with null instead of the Event. check it out.

```
 comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                jTable1MouseClicked(null);
            }
        });


 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            //evt.getPoint();
            System.out.println("row" + jTable1.getSelectedRow());
            System.out.println("col" + jTable1.getSelectedColumn());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

may be its not Right way but i solved it this threw. its working.

best solution is

```
jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Changed Column"+e.getColumn());
                System.out.println("first row"+e.getFirstRow());
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: That's going to cause a `null` pointer exception as your going to want to use the `MouseEvent` information...just saying...

Comment: @MadProgrammer but i did not get Exception its working according to my req. and ya its giving me the count. i know u are right it not proper solution. but please suggest me another good na.

Comment: How can it not give you `NullPointerException` when you do `evt.getPoint()` in the `jTable1MouseClicked` method?

Comment: @MadProgrammer bro i am not calling that method. look i have updated that method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer and u are right it will give null pointer if we use e.getPoint(); :)

Comment: It's possible that more then one row or column could be selected (unlikely, by possible)

Comment: @MadProgrammer U are right Bro. it could be possible and ya look what i did again m editing that.